# How to load product image in powerbi from server

Tags: powerbi

I need to display product image per product in powerbi.
and my image is located in local server.
how I can load to power BI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look at the Chiclet Slicer visual in the gallery ([https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/](http://Visuals%20Gallery)) this will allow you to present several images and filter your data based on the selected image. Otherwise you can try Image Viewer as well in the Visuals Gallery to display individual images. In order to get your images into Power BI you can use Get Data and then for example select Folder for the location in your server. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: I already tried using but I cannot load from my local drive. image cannot show. ex : D:/image/22.jpg

Comment: I downloaded the example report for the Chiclet Slicer visual and it has the following notes in case it helps: (1) Image field defines image that will be displayed inside a chiclet. It should contain URLs of images. (2) URLs that do not require authentication are supported only. URLs to local files are not supported.

Comment: yes it look like cannot support local files. I need that. And also I already tried image viewer visual and get the same result